# What's a "corner" in a parameter space?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm learning about Hamiltonian Monte Carlo and one of the stated benefits is that it can move around a parameter space more efficiently and that it can (from *Bayesian Data Analysis*, 3rd ed.)

> turn corners in parameter space to preserve the total 'energy' of the trajectory.

What does *BDA* mean by a "corner" in the parameter space and why wouldn't a Gibbs or Metropolis-Hastings sampler be able to "turn the corner?"

Comment: This blog post might be relevant:  http://andrewgelman.com/2017/03/15/ensemble-methods-doomed-fail-high-dimensions/